# Is a road trip from Kuwait to Bahrain by company vehicle possible? What is the procedure and paperworks?

Tags: transit, saudi-arabia, kuwait, bahrain

We are planing a road trip from Kuwait to Bahrain by company vehicle and I got many details from here. But does anyone know the rules and documentation for using a company car instead of private car? We are not sure we can use company vehicle for this.

Comment: Do you have the company's permission to do the trip in its car? You may need documents to prove that, such as a letter from a company officer.

Comment: we will get the permission from my company if its possible to travel by company car. if its possible then what are the documents we need to carry.

Comment: Relevant but not an exact duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41873/how-to-get-saudi-arabian-transit-visa-for-road-travel

Comment: VTC: too broad, as it requires research into vehicle and insurance laws in three countries (and for entry into two). OP has not returned since posting.

Comment: You'll need a letter allowing you to take the car across the border; as you are not the registered owner. Other than that, you have no other specific requirements.