I have a UK passport. Do I need a transit visa to travel by car through Saudi Arabia to Jordan?
I’m a British citizen with a UAE residence visa. Where or how do I get a transit visa to travel to Jordan by car. I will travel through Saudi so do I need a transit visa? If so can it be obtained from the border or what steps should I take.

Welcome to TSE. What has your own research on this revealed? For example, foreign travel advice for British citizens?

Traversing the whole country by car is not what is usually referred to as "transit".

@littleadv Crossing Saudi Arabia by car to get to another country is, in fact, a perfectly valid reason to get a Saudi transit visa.

See also this Q&A, although it's old enough that it's not an exact dupe: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41873/how-to-get-saudi-arabian-transit-visa-for-road-travel

Yes, you absolutely do need a visa, the question is which one.
Saudi transit visas were useful in the days that Saudi Arabia did not issue tourist visas, but now that they do, you're probably better off getting one of those instead, they're a bit more expensive but much more flexible.  You can (and should) apply online, see I am transiting through Saudi Arabia. Do I need a visa? for details.
